# Добавление элементов в String[]

Tags: java

Привет,опять возникла проблема,имеется строка и массив:

```
String[] list;
String text;
```

Задача такая,строка текст имеет значение,его надо добавить в массив list,подскажите,пожалуйста,как это сделать?Опять же за код спасибо большое)

Comment: Может быть вам будет полезнее почитать руководство по синтаксису и основным операциям языка? Так вы гораздо быстрее решите свою задачу.

Comment: мне одному кажется, что настолько глупые вопросы только во вред форуму?

Comment: Почитал предыдущие вопросы его, странно,, что такое спрашивает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] list;
String text;

list = new String[1];
list[0] = text;
```

Comment: Спасибо.А вот если много объектов,и добавлять их так накладно,можно какой-нибудь автоматический процесс

Comment: @ваняя: попробуйте цикл.

Answer (score 1):

если Вы четко знаете какого размера у Вас будет массив строк, тогда лучше использовать метод указанный выше. А вот если у Вас не известно сколько элементов будет в массиве используйте лучше ArrayList<String>. А по ссылке написано как просто можно работать с данным массивом http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: А не боитесь потока вопросов от автора про "непонятную магею"? Листы и дженерики стоит осознавать уже после того, как разобрался с массивами и основами синтаксиса языка...

Comment: На вопросы про магию, я отвечаю просто - Это магия и никакого волшебства